# Moving navigation bar to the top while scrolling down in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to make the navigation bar stick to the top when scrolling down.
It's easy when the navbar is on top, but since I placed a Div above it I can't seem to figure it out. I tried position fixed and others didnt work.
for example like this website www.screencult.com. And btw I'm using Bootstarp.

Here's what I have so far
[This is what I have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8OJpy.jpg)

```
<div id="nav" class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navHeaderCollapse">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                        <li><a href="#description" id="color" >ABOUT US</a></li>
                        <li><a id="color" href="#" >GALLERY</a></li>
                        <li><a id="color" href="#contactus" >CONTACT US</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div> 

#nav {
    background-color: white;
    border: none;
    border-style: none;
}
#color {
    color: #b5be35; 
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: color 0.5s ease;
}
#color:hover {
    color: #a1a5a2;
}
```

Comment: There is no pure CSS way to do it. You have to change the style of the bar to fixed as you scroll down the page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change to position fixed after you have scrolled to a certain point on the page. eg the height of the image.

We use a scroll even listener and scroll top to find out how far we have scrolled

```
window.addEventListener("scroll", function(e){
      var scrollTop = (window.pageYOffset !== undefined) ? window.pageYOffset : (document.documentElement || document.body.parentNode || document.body).scrollTop;
      //If we have scrolled far enough on the page to be past the image
      //Change the nav to have fixed positioning
      var imageHeight = document.getElementById("image-header").clientHeight
      var nav = document.getElementById("nav");
      if(scrollTop > imageHeight){
          nav.classList.add("fixed-nav");
      }
      else{
          nav.classList.remove("fixed-nav");
      }

});
```